# unable to locate xpath selenium, even it is present in the html

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to scrape the address and email from  HTML code using xpath .

//*[@id="divbody"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table

this is the xpath, I am typing it correctly till I get error.

screen shot of HTML code

[image]

Comment: I want to scrape name address and phone number using xpath.

Comment: Please add the error you get.

Comment: this is the error i get   :                                                                                                                                 NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='divbody']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/font/strong"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Comment: Open 'Console' and open the 'fames' dropdown. Maybe you have deal with iFrames. In this case search how to switch to the needed frame before working with the webElement.

Comment: this is not an i frame, it is pure HTML but I  am unable to scrap.